# Unable to find module: react-accordion component

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am making accordion in react-native.I have taken the following steps:

1) In my react-native project I have install react-accordion-component by using following commond:

```
npm install --save react-accordion-component
```

2) Import it to `index.android.js`:

```
'use strict';
import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  PropTypes,
  ToastAndroid,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ViewPagerAndroid,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { Tab, TabLayout } from 'react-native-android-tablayout';
import 'react-accordion-component';



class POC extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pagePosition: 0,
    };
  }



  render() {

    var Accordion = require('react-accordion-component');
var elements = [];
elements.push({
    title: 'Element 1',
    onClick: function() {
      alert('Hello World!')
    },
    content: 'Lorem Ipsum...'
  });

elements.push({
  title: 'Element 2',
  onClick: function() {
  },
  content: 'Lorem Ipsum...'
});
    return (
       <View>
        <TabLayout
          style={styles.tabLayout}
          selectedTab={this.state.pagePosition}
          onTabSelected={_setPagePosition.bind(this)}>
          <Tab name="S"/>
          <Tab name="O"/>
          <Tab name="A"/>
      <Tab name="p"/>
        </TabLayout>
        <ViewPagerAndroid
          style={styles.viewPager}
          ref={viewPager => { this.viewPager = viewPager; }}
          onPageSelected={_setPagePosition.bind(this)}>
          <View >
             React.render(<Accordion elements={elements} />, document.getElementById('accordion-example'));
          </View>
          <View style={styles.content}>
            <Text>Tab 2 content</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.content}>
            <Text>Tab 3 content</Text>
          </View>
      <View style={styles.content}>
            <Text>Tab 4 content</Text>
          </View>
        </ViewPagerAndroid>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

 function _setPagePosition(e:Event) {
    const pagePosition = e.nativeEvent.position;
    this.setState({ pagePosition });
    // too bad ViewPagerAndroid doesn't support prop updates,
    // work around by forwarding changes using exposed API
    this.viewPager.setPage(pagePosition);
  }


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabLayout: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ddd'
  },
  viewPager: {
    height: 200,
  },
  content: {
    padding: 10,
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('POC', () => POC);
```

But when run on the emulator, it gives the following error:

> Requiring unknown module "react-accordion-component".

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have these two statements going on:

**At the top of your file:**

import  `react-accordion-component`

**And in render function:**

`var Accordion = require('react-accordion-component')`

Delete the import statement, and replace it with

`var Accordion = require('react-accordion-component')`

So, it should basically look like this now:

```
'use strict';
import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  PropTypes,
  ToastAndroid,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ViewPagerAndroid,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { Tab, TabLayout } from 'react-native-android-tablayout';
var Accordion = require('react-accordion-component');

class POC extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pagePosition: 0,
    };
  }

  render() {
    var elements = [];
    elements.push({
      title: 'Element 1',
      onClick: function() {
      alert('Hello World!')
    },
    content: 'Lorem Ipsum...'
  });
...
```